# Are there any difference for web browser when backend use webflux or simple rest controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-async, spring-reactor

Assume we have a 2 rest services:

```
// a rest controller
@GetMapping
private List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeRepository.findAllEmployees();
}
```

// another controller

```
@GetMapping
private Flux<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeRepository.findAllEmployees(); // suppose reactive db driver here
}
```

a there any difference for client's web browser between this code?

Comment: Yes, one is streamed to the client the other is not.

Comment: So does it mean the web browser will keep a http connection until the stream is closed?

Comment: It all depends on how you call the service, using the address field, javascript client, Server Sent Events etc.

Comment: ok, in case of simple rest get request in address bar, what will browser do?

Comment: Why dont you just try it and see what happens, Look in the debug meny (F12) while you do it and then update your question when you have some specific questions or run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Normal Rest Controller**: Suppose server is going to return some 10000 records.In this case the server waits for the database to return all the data and this data is forwarded as response. So you recieve all the response in one shot in the mean time, browser will be continuosly loading with blank page and thats a bad experience in this modern era

**Reactive Controller**: In webflux spring Reactive Controller their is a concept of **back pressure**. In *back pressure their is open connection between server and database, so whatever the records have been received will be continuously emitted as a response*. Hence no blank screen and better user experience.

*Note*: The connection between browser will remain intact till the time all data is loaded in browser

Comment: Thank you! So will the browser start to receive records chunks? Will it keep the connection? Or need to establish a new connection for every chunk?

Comment: @cpu if the browser support it, it will communicate with Server Sent Event (SSE) that retain the connection. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: @AdhikaSetyaPramudita, how about chrome?

Comment: @cpu according to compatibility table at the end of page, chrome is supported.